# ClassCastException [C cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using Spark MLlib's DecisionTreeModel for prediction.

```
 def predict(sc: SparkContext) : (Row => Row) = {
      val model = DecisionTreeModel.load(sc,"hdfs://invlxiisqa09.informatica.com:8020/user/cloudqa/anuja/myDecisionTreeClassificationModel")
     (str:Row)=> {
      val mldata5 = Vectors.dense( str.get(0).asInstanceOf[Int],str.get(1).asInstanceOf[Int],  str.get(2).asInstanceOf[Int] ,  str.get(3).asInstanceOf[Int], str.get(4).asInstanceOf[Int],  str.get(5).asInstanceOf[Int], str.get(6).asInstanceOf[Int], str.get(7).asInstanceOf[Int])
      val prediction = Row.fromSeq(String.valueOf(model.predict(mldata5)).toSeq)
      prediction
     }        
}
```

When I send the following data

```
[12.0,0.0,1620.0,1850.0,6.0,270.0,234.0,270.0]
```

I get a `ClassCastException` while creating a Row.

Can someone point me where I'm wrong?

Stacktrace is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [C cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$.fromSeq(Row.scala:53)
at com.informatica.bootstrap.InfaStreaming$$anonfun$predicts$1.apply(InfaStreaming.scala:256)
at com.informatica.bootstrap.InfaStreaming$$anonfun$predicts$1.apply(InfaStreaming.scala:253)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at com.informatica.bootstrap.InfaStreaming$$anonfun$jsonPayloadGenerator$1$$anon$3.next(InfaStreaming.scala:946)
at com.informatica.bootstrap.InfaStreaming$$anonfun$jsonPayloadGenerator$1$$anon$3.next(InfaStreaming.scala:943)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:31)
at com.informatica.adapter.streaming.kafka.common.KafkaOperations.sendMessagesBinary(KafkaOperations.java:308)
at com.informatica.bootstrap.InfaStreaming$$anonfun$writeToKafka$2$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(InfaStreaming.scala:274)
at com.informatica.bootstrap.InfaStreaming$$anonfun$writeToKafka$2$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(InfaStreaming.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:925)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:925)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can post full stacktrace?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: [C cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$.fromSeq(Row.scala:53)

Answer (score 0):

**Java ClassCastException**

A Java ClassCastException is an Exception that can occur when you try to **improperly convert a class from one type to another**. ... Because a String cannot be directly cast to an Integer — an Integer is not a type of String — a ClassCastException is thrown in java.

Comment: thanks. but here i'm not converting string to integer. Exception is thrown during creating Row

Answer (score 0):

**This conversion of String to Integer:**

def tryToInt( s: String ) = Try(s.toInt).toOption

**In Your Code may try to apply like  this...**

val prediction = Row.fromSeq(tryToInt( s: String )=Try((model.predict(mldata5.toInt)).toSeq)

Answer (score 0):

Something in your row is not an Int, and when you try to cast it to an int, it's failing. To troubleshoot, I would try printing out everything in the row and seeing what's in there. Sometimes when you load data the types that columns are marshalled into can be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and it worked for me:

Try

```
val prediction = Row(String.valueOf(model.p....
```

instead of

```
val prediction = Row.fromSeq(String.valueOf(model.p....
```